# Creating new column based on criteria in three other columns

Tags: r

Can anyone help me create a new column based on some strict criteria.

Data looks like this

```
screening consistancyAPP  consistancyVAF consistancyCRF
XXX/01    Missing         50-100% target 50-100% target
XXX/03    0-49% target    0-49% target   0-49% target
XXX/08    Missing         Missing        50-100% target
XXX/13    Missing         Missing        Missing
XXX/09    Missing         0-49% target   50-100% target
XXX/04    0-49% target    0-49% target   50-100% target
```

```
df <- data.frame (screening  = c("XXX/01", "XXX/03", "XXX/08","XXX/13","XXX/09","XXX/04"),
                  consistancyAPP = c("Missing", "0-49% target", "Missing","Missing","Missing","0-49% target"),
                  consistancyVAF = c("50-100% target", "0-49% target", "Missing","Missing","0-49% target","0-49% target"),
                  consistancyCRF = c("50-100% target", "0-49% target", "50-100% target","Missing","50-100% target","50-100% target")
)
```

Conditions of the new column

- if all three the same e.g. Missing then Missing
- if two Missing (e.g. XXX/08) then take the other (e.g. 50-100% target)
- if two in agreement (e.g. XXX/01) then that value (e.g. 50-100% target)
- if all three different (XXX/09) take the lower (0-49% target)

I want the output to look like this

```
screening consistancyAPP  consistancyVAF consistancyCRF  consistancyOverall
XXX/01    Missing         50-100% target 50-100% target  50-100% target
XXX/04    0-49% target    0-49% target   0-49% target    0-49% target
XXX/08    Missing         Missing        50-100% target  50-100% target
XXX/13    Missing         Missing        Missing         Missing
XXX/09    Missing         0-49% target   50-100% target  0-49% target
XXX/04    0-49% target    0-49% target   50-100% target  0-49% target
```

Comment: Are in your example all the possible cases? Is it possible that in your data there is something like 30-40% target?

Comment: Can only be 'Missing', '0-49% target', '50-100% target'. These are the only three levels

Comment: As you say, your column values are factors. Hence, you could convert to `factor(..., ordered = TRUE)` and use it to pick the result. It would be way easier to help you, if you could provide a working example, so that we do not need to create the data.frame ourselves.

Comment: Added a working example !

Answer (score 2):

Ok I finally got my function to work.
For this problem I created a function that takes a character vector of length 3 and based on the conditions above returns the preferred choice. We then use dplyr functions `rowwise` and `mutate` to apply it on every column of your data set:

```
score <- function(symbols) {
  
  same <- symbols[1] == symbols[2] && symbols[2] == symbols[3]
  two_same <- symbols[1] == symbols[2] || symbols[2] == symbols[[3]] ||
    symbols[1] == symbols[3]
  not_same <- symbols[1] != symbols[2] && symbols[1] != symbols[2] &&
    symbols[2] != symbols[3]
  two_missing <- sum(symbols == "Missing") == 2
  
  if(same) {
    return(symbols[1])
  } else if(not_same) {
    return("0-49% target")
  } else if(two_missing) {
    return(symbols[symbols != "Missing"])
  } else if(two_same) {
    return(symbols[duplicated(symbols)])
  }
}

x <- c("Missing", "50-100% target", "50-100% target")

score(x)
[1] "50-100% target"

y <- c("Missing", "0-49% target", "50-100% target")

score(y)
[1] "0-49% target"

z <- c("Missing", "Missing", "50-100% target")

score(z)
[1] "50-100% target"
```

Now we apply it on your data set as follows:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(consistancyOverall = score(c_across(starts_with('consistancy'))))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Rowwise: 
  screening consistancyAPP consistancyVAF consistancyCRF consistancyOverall
  <chr>     <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>             
1 XXX/01    Missing        50-100% target 50-100% target 50-100% target    
2 XXX/03    0-49% target   0-49% target   0-49% target   0-49% target      
3 XXX/08    Missing        Missing        50-100% target 50-100% target    
4 XXX/13    Missing        Missing        Missing        Missing           
5 XXX/09    Missing        0-49% target   50-100% target 0-49% target      
6 XXX/04    0-49% target   0-49% target   50-100% target 0-49% target
```

And you can also use `pmap` from `purrr` function, however, this time we don't use `rowwise` because `pmap` applies a function on every row of a data frame by itself:

```
df %>%
  mutate(consistancyOverall = pmap(list(consistancyAPP, consistancyVAF, consistancyCRF), 
                                   ~ score(c(...))))

  screening consistancyAPP consistancyVAF consistancyCRF consistancyOverall
1    XXX/01        Missing 50-100% target 50-100% target     50-100% target
2    XXX/03   0-49% target   0-49% target   0-49% target       0-49% target
3    XXX/08        Missing        Missing 50-100% target     50-100% target
4    XXX/13        Missing        Missing        Missing            Missing
5    XXX/09        Missing   0-49% target 50-100% target       0-49% target
6    XXX/04   0-49% target   0-49% target 50-100% target       0-49% target
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function which returns the output based on condition and apply to for each row.

```
library(dplyr)

calculateOverall <- function(x) {
  tmp <- sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)
            #If all three are same
  case_when(n_distinct(x) == 1 ~ first(x),
            #If two missing take other
            sum(x == 'Missing') >= 2 ~ x[x!= 'Missing'][1], 
            #If two in agreement take that value
            tmp[1] >= 2 ~ names(tmp)[1], 
            #If all three different
            n_distinct(tmp) == 1 ~ '0-49% target')
}

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(consistancyOverall = calculateOverall(c_across(starts_with('consistancy'))))

# screening consistancyAPP consistancyVAF consistancyCRF consistancyOverall
#  <chr>     <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>             
#1 XXX/01    Missing        50-100% target 50-100% target 50-100% target    
#2 XXX/03    0-49% target   0-49% target   0-49% target   0-49% target      
#3 XXX/08    Missing        Missing        50-100% target 50-100% target    
#4 XXX/13    Missing        Missing        Missing        Missing           
#5 XXX/09    Missing        0-49% target   50-100% target 0-49% target      
#6 XXX/04    0-49% target   0-49% target   50-100% target 0-49% target
```

Or with `purrr::pmap_chr` :

```
df %>%
  mutate(consistancyOverall = purrr::pmap_chr(select(., starts_with('consistancy')),
                              ~calculateOverall(c(...))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great contribution, I really appreciate it. I only have one question in this case can we use `purrr` functions to apply a function on these 3 columns rowwise?

Comment: Yes, we can use `pmap_chr`. I updated the answer to include that option as well.

Comment: I finally got my function to work for this problem and I don't know how to thank you. It would have been a pity for me to just leave it after spending a considerable time on it, I am just glad it finally worked. Thank you for your cooperation on this you will be forever one of my inspiration in R.

Comment: Glad, that you were able to make it work @AnoushiravanR . All the best.